# CSS: Add right floating content to a centered container

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I am trying to append some content to a `th` container where the text is centered. I want the new content to be at the very right of the container, and keep the current text centered.

```
|--------content--------|
```

to

```
|--------content-------a|
```

where a is the new content.

I have seen a couple of similar posts, but can't find one that is relevant. I can easily do a float left , right, clear both to keep a on the right and content on the left, but I specifically want to keep content where it is. Also, I don't want content to be shifted to the left due to the presence of a if possible.

Comment: we need to know what you're appending

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.  Use `position: relative` on the `th` and then use absolute positioning for the appended element, `b` in my example.

```css
table {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 100%;
}
table th {
  position: relative;
}
table th div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Centered Content <div>A</div></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, but my 'A' is going to be a div element, will this still work?

Comment: The technique works with `div` and most other elements.  I tweaked the example for you to use a `div`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need.

```html
<table width="200px" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <th> <span style=" text-align:center;">content </span><span style="float:right;">1</span>
    </th>
  </tbody>
</table>
```